# Azure AD Application Roles Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've created an App Role in Azure AD. I've applied that Role to an AD Group I'm in. I've added Authorization to the program.cs  Any page I go to in the /Admin folder, I get Access Denied.  If I check `user.IsInRole("Asset Database Admin")` it's false. Where am I going wrong?

Relevant program.cs code

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(ops => { 
    ops.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin", "IsAdmin");
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(config.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Asset Database Admin"));
});
```

[image]

Comment: missing `app.UseAuthorization()`?

Comment: @lloyd thanks.  it's not missing from my code...just wasn't included here.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the role-based-access with AAD, so we first need to create app role in app registion and then assign the custom-created-app role to the user or group in enterprise application. Like what you did indicating in the screenshot. Here I have a custom role named as `Tiny.AccessEndpoint`, and since I don't have an AAD Premium P1 or P2 edition, so I could only assign roles to users [but not groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal?pivots=portal).

[image]

Then we could have these code in the program.cs to add the policy.

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options =>
{
    // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are available.
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
});

// Adding authorization policies that enforce authorization using Azure AD roles.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("mypolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("Tiny.AccessEndpoint"));
    options.AddPolicy("policy2", policy => policy.RequireRole("tinyUser"));
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Then in the controller, enable the policy by adding `[Authorize(Policy = "mypolicy")]` attribute. Then when I sign in with the account that assigned the role, I would be able to visit the site, if I used another policy, then using this account would get access denied error.

[image]

By the way, if what you want is allow users in specific group to sign visit the protected site, you might need to add `options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "groups";` as well, while the policy should have like this `options.AddPolicy("MemberGroupRequired", policy => policy.RequireRole("group_1_id","group_2_id"));`

sample for user role: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles

sample for group: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups

Comment: I added the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;` and the `builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
});` I still get the same result.

Comment: Hi, the roles you created is assigned to groups, so could you pls try to add the code snippets I shared at the end of my reply as well?

Comment: I added the `options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "groups";`  Same result.  Still getting Access Denied.

Comment: the policy you owned now is `"IsAdmin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Asset Database Admin")`, could you pls change `set Database Admin` to the `groupid`. I'm so sorry because I didn't have `AAD Premium P1 or P2 ` so I can't test your scenario in my side. Anyway, if all of my code snippet didn't work for you, you might also following the official sample I shared in the link.

Comment: I tried both the group id  and the role id.  neither worked.  I get access denied with both.

Comment: I'm sorry and I don't have any other ideas on your issue then... because it really worked in my side.