# Role-based Authorization not working properly in Asp.Net Framework Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

I connected an application to Azure AD and created  Approles  SMTRole and ITRole to authorize views and assigned security groups SMT-Report and IT-Report respectively to the roles. I've also configured claims SMTRole and ITRole for the two roles.

As shown in my controller below, the members of the SMT-Report security group assigned to the SMTrole should only see the  EmbedReport view and not the EmbedReport1 and vice versa for the members of the IT-Report security group.

However, this is not working properly as any user that is a member of any of the two groups, sees the two pages with no restriction and  a user that is not a member of any of the two groups gets "no access " notification.

please i need help, i've tried all i could from the documentations but i don't see to know what is wrong

```
namespace PowerBIEmbedded_AppOwnsData.Controllers
{
    public class FinanceController : Controller

    {
        private string m_errorMessage;

        public FinanceController()
        {
            m_errorMessage = ConfigValidatorService.GetWebConfigErrors();
        }
        [Authorize(Roles = "ITRole")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EmbedReport()
        {

            var embedResult = await EmbedService.GetEmbedParams(ConfigValidatorService.WorkspaceId, ConfigValidatorService.ReportIds);
            return View(embedResult);

        }
        [Authorize(Roles = "SMTRole")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EmbedReport1()
        {

            var embedResult = await EmbedService.GetEmbedParams(ConfigValidatorService.WorkspaceId, ConfigValidatorService.ReportIds);
            return View(embedResult);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Asp.Net Framework`? can you clarify what exact framework and version you use?

Comment: Adding the attributes is rarely enough. You need to configure the system with the kind of auth system you intend to use (OAuth2, etc.). https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles

Comment: I [have a test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77133044/14574199) before and you might take a look at it and see it if could help you.

Comment: @EmreBener  it's an MVC Version 4.8

Comment: it's not an asp.net core app right? not core app.

Comment: @TinyWang  Thanks for the article. No, it is not